# Periodic MASSIVE ping spikes that start a few minutes after startup

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-adapter, lag, latency

I am having extremely frustrating latency spikes every 10 or so seconds on my network connection.

It is very consistent and it always spikes for around 1600ms at a time, and it only happens maybe 10-15m after startup (so for the first few minutes there will be no problem)

Some quick info to start with:

1. No Malware or viruses detected by MalwareBytes or MSE
2. All drivers have been fully updated
3. No nearby interference
4. Not a hardware problem, as I tried the SAME network adapter on my laptop and it's perfectly normal (also after leaving it for a period of time)
5. No irregularities in network resource monitor (almost 0% network utilization too)
6. Tried disabling autoconfiguration logic for the wireless adapter

Despite all that however, I am still getting these massive but consistent ping spikes recently, when the only change I've made today was update my GPU drivers (Radeon ReLive).

I am really frustrated as I have no idea what is causing the problem and I have no idea how to diagnose it, really hope someone might have a good suggestion for this

EDIT:

**Wireless Adapter:** D-Link DWA-123 N150 Wireless USB Adapter

**Driver:** 1027.2.1001.2014 (latest version on this site: http://www.dlink.com.sg/dwa-123-d1/)
*interesting to note that though the site says the publish date was 03/22/2016 in device manager it says the driver date is 11/13/2014

As for the wireless signal, it's WPA-2 Personal (AES) from a Huawei HG8245H router (provided by ISP) and it's at maximum strength (only a few feet away through a wooden wall) but only showing 65Mbps in speed

Comment: Could you please describe the hardware you are using, such as your network adapter model, driver version, and any information about the wireless signal from your router (also protocol)?

Comment: BlackVulcan, have you tried using this adapter in a different USB port? I have experienced a similar issue in one of my laptops, and it was due to a failing USB port. Also, what version of Windows is this, and do you have your USB/chipset drivers up to date? Good to cross these things off

Comment: USB/chipset drivers aren't fully updated I think, I'll try to update them when I get back and post an update. As for the version of Windows it is the WIndows 7 Ultimate Edition with all the latest updates (not sure where to find the exact version)

Answer (score 0):

Just confirmed that the issue is due to the new Radeon ReLive update for my graphics card. It is an issue centered around the ReLive functionality (similar to Nvidia Shadowplay) that causes issues for certain wireless network adapters.

The current workaround until this is patched is typing "netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface="INSERT WIRELESS CONNECTION NAME HERE" " in cmd (note that you need to turn it back on or else when you disconnect, you will not be able to reconnect as wifi autoconfig is disabled) or disabling ReLive.